# ng serve - Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'

Tags: angular

Starting ng serve I see Errors:

```
ERROR in lista-zadan-repo/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error         
TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
```

I'm just lerning Angular and it is difficult to say what was done exactly before errors. Probably also Angular update can be an issue. I tried all sollutions from other stackoverflow topics symilar to this but didn't help. 
I'd like to solve issue to lern instead of starting new project.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],

    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}


ng --version

Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Renderer installed?

Comment: One of my favorite things to do when upgrading is to do a new application in a different folder and then I can diff the config files and see what may change between versions.

Comment: @RobertLove I simply use angular-cli-diff to do that: https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff

Comment: "Do you have multiple versions of Renderer installed?" How can I check it?